# Add comparison parameter in where clause if condition satishfied

Tags: sql, where-clause, rdbms

I want to add comparison parameter in where clause only if my input parameter is not null. I tried below query but its giving me error.

```
CASE 
     WHEN ( 
           (SELECT TOP 1 (AMOUNT + ISNULL((@p_iAmountRequested * FEEPERCENTAGE), 0.0)) 
            FROM CONVEYANCERLEGALFEE VF1 
            WHERE VF1.CONVEYANCERLEGALFEESET = MP.CONVEYANCERLEGALFEESET 
            AND VF1.LOCATION = @p_iLocation 
            AND VF1.TYPEOFAPPLICATION =@p_iTypeOfApplication
            AND VF1.MAXIMUMVALUE >= @p_iAmountRequested
            --buyer type condition is not working                  
            AND 
                case when (@p_iTypeOfBuyer is not null) THEN
                           (VF1.TYPEOFBUYER = @p_iTypeOfBuyer)
                END
            AND CONVEYANCERLEGALFEESETSTRTDATE = 
                              (SELECT MAX(CONVEYANCERLEGALFEESETSTRTDATE) 
                                  FROM CONVEYANCERLEGALFEE VF2 
                                  WHERE VF1.CONVEYANCERLEGALFEESET = VF2.CONVEYANCERLEGALFEESET 
                                  AND VF1.LOCATION = VF2.LOCATION
                                  --AND VF1.TYPEOFBUYER = vf2.TYPEOFBUYER 
                                  AND VF1.TYPEOFAPPLICATION = VF2.TYPEOFAPPLICATION 
                                  AND VF1.MAXIMUMVALUE = VF2.MAXIMUMVALUE) 
                               ORDER BY VF1.MAXIMUMVALUE ASC ) = 0.0) 
                          THEN 1
                        ELSE 0 
                    END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `CASE` statement to achieve such a thing you can use `COALESCE`. You didn't tag your question with the RDBMs you are using, though almost all databases support it.

Do as:

```
...
AND yourFieldToTest = coalesce(@yourParameter, yourFieldToTest)
...
```

`COALESCE` will return the first non null argument so if `@yourParameter` is null then the condition will be `yourFieldToTest = yourFieldToTest` which will be true same as if isn't there at all.

Side note, `COALESCE` it can receive multiple parameters with the same rule, it will return the first non null like `coalesce(@param1, @param2, @param3, whateverColumn, etc)`

And in your Query:

```
AND VF1.TYPEOFBUYER = coalesce(@p_iTypeOfBuyer, VF1.TYPEOFBUYER)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However it includes VF1.TYPEOFBUYER for comparison. I do not wish to add it into comparison list is @p_iTypeOfBuyer is null. Where clause should skip this parameter if its null

Comment: It will include yes, but since your parameter is null it will process it as `VF1.TYPEOFBUYER = VF1.TYPEOFBUYER` which is true in any situation so it doesn't matter that it is there or not. There is no way other than a dynamic query to not add that column in the joins. even if you manage to do it with a case statement the right way it will be in the query

Comment: You are right Sir. It works as expected. Thank you very much

Comment: Please mark it as accepted. To do so, click on the V icon in the left side of the answer. Cheers,

Comment: Solution Accepted. Cheers.